# How to use svelte store with react.js

Tags: reactjs, svelte-3

Is there a way to use svelte store with react.js. I really like it's simplicity and how it's replace `switch` `case`. Here's an example code from svelte doc.

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

function createCount() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(0);

    return {
        subscribe,
        increment: () => {},
        decrement: () => {},
        reset: () => {}
    };
}

export const count = createCount();
```

Answer (score 13):

This is easily do-able with React hooks:

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {get} from 'svelte/store';

const unset = Symbol();

export function useReadable(store) {
  const [value, set] = useState(unset);

  useEffect(() => store.subscribe(set), [store]);

  return value === unset ? get(store) : value;
}

export function useWritable(store) {
  const [value, set] = useState(unset);

  useEffect(() => store.subscribe(set), [store]);

  return [
    value === unset ? get(store) : value,
    store.set,
    store.update
  ];
}
```

**EDIT**

After this answer I actually packaged this up. The code has been used in in production. It's straightforward to understand. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-svelte-store

Comment: I think your useEffect should return an unsubscribe call, to avoid memory leak. (or make another useEffect with no dependency that returns an unsbuscribe).

Comment: It does! :) `subscribe` returns the cancellation function and `() => x` lambdas return `x`, so *that* useEffect returns cancellation.

Comment: Oh yes, of course! 

Comment: Question 1: why not simply write `useState(get(store))` instead of the unset thingie? Question 2: is `[store]` really necessary in the useEffect? I can't imagine the store itself changing...

Comment: `get(...)` is expensive, and hooks get run and rerun frequently. Without the `unset` symbol you have no way to distinguish between 'unset' and null/falsey values.  _Nothing_ stops anyone from handing a different store in subsequent calls. If you _use_ something that is not guaranteed stable then you need to depend on that thing. By depending on the store this hook will unsubscribe to the old one and automatically resubscribe to the new one.